# Notation for Restriction of Permutation

Tags: combinatorics, notation, permutations

Suppose $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are permutations such that $\sigma(x)\not=x\implies \sigma(x)=\tau(x)$. Intuitively, I would like to think of $\sigma$ as a restriction (or projection) of $\tau$ onto a restricted subspace. Another way of phrasing this: the cycle of structure of $\sigma$ is "contained" in the cycle structure of $\tau$.

However, I do not know the proper terminology to express this. I would like to write something like $\sigma \subset \tau$, without being misleading. Can anyone suggest the proper terminology or notation for this situation?

Comment: I don't think this kind of relation is often considered. But if you need to coin new terminology, you might think of something like calling $\sigma$ a "divisor" of $\tau$, in analogy to number theory (but you'd need to avoid confusion with "$\tau=\pi\sigma$ for some $\pi$", which is of course always true.

Comment: I expected there to already be a notation for this. Should I repost to mathoverflow perhaps?